# Why is this NGINX config file invalid?

Tags: nginx, https, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

So I have this NGINX config file:

```
events { }
http {
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /home/dietpi/certs/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/dietpi/certs/privkey.pem.key;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:3001/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
}
```

It is a reverse-proxy for a Docker container. It does SSL for me. I wanted to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, so I tried adding this:

```
events { }
http {
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /home/dietpi/certs/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/dietpi/certs/privkey.pem.key;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:3001/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
}
```

But now it doesn't work (`sudo nginx -t` fails).
It says this:

```
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Most people that have this error tend to have the server block not in an `http` block, and putting it in one fixes it. But... my `server` block is already in an `http` block. So how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo is `server` instead of `server_name` within the `server {}` block

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;   # ✅ corrected
}
```